# What's faster: SFTP or FTP via SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, ssh-tunnel

I find SFTP very slow in WinSCP, especially when many small files have to be transferred. Will FTP via SSH tunnel be faster?

Comment: Probably not. But it would be nice to see some speed measurements from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tunneling FTP through SSH will add another layer of overhead to the process.

You're probably better off sticking with using SFTP.

Perhaps you should try switching your WinSCP to SCP mode and see if it improves performance.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it's a bit faster with SCP, but not a big difference.